# MAMP: AJAX only runs from certain directory

Tags: jquery, mamp

Running a page including AJAX (jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.1) through MAMP(2.1.3) on Chrome(29.0.1547.76). System is a super-stripped-down example of [wtfdiary.com: like button](http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/06/like-button-similar-to-facebook-to-vote.html)

Enter problem. If i place the files in root, the page loads, but never runs the AJAX script, when button is clicked. If i place the files in subfolders, it sometimes runs, sometimes doesn't (seems completely random). Renaming sometimes helps instantly. Sometimes I just have to wait for a few hours, it seems.

Please help. I'm a huge rookie at everything, so simple answers please.
Thanks  :)

Page works like this: Push button on ajax.php. text appears next to button "string return" and JS error message appears "alert return".

(start page) Ajax.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="like_message.js"></script>
<title>
AJAX.PHP
</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

$msg_id="jesus";
$like_count=2;
echo "<a href='' id='$msg_id' class='like_button'><img src='vote_up.png'/></a>&nbsp;<span class='like_show$msg_id'>$like_count</span>";

?>

</body>

</html>
```

(JS) like_message.js

```
$(function() {

$(".like_button").click(function() 
{
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "message_like.php",
//   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)
   {
//    $(".like_show"+like_id).html(html);

  }  });

return false;
    });

});
```

(AJAX-called PHP) message_like.php

```
<?php
echo "string return";
echo "<script language=javascript>alert('alert return')</script>";
?>
```

Comment: I *think* you need to prefix the url parameter of the ajax call with "/folder/file.php". the beginning "/" tells it to start at the root of your server.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. It doesn't do the trick, though